# Python Socket:Handling multiple connection with same socket

Tags: python, sockets

My question is related to socket.close() function. Once we call this inside our program do we have to restate the socket definition to start a new connection. This code is working,

```
     import socket
     sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
     result1 = sock.connect_ex(('127.0.0.1',9001))
     sock.close()
     sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
     result2 = sock.connect_ex(('127.0.0.1',8119))
     sock.close()
```

This connection returns "0" as output(result1,result2) after every socket call..
But I need something like this one,

```
 import socket
 sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
 result1 = sock.connect_ex(('127.0.0.1',9001))
 result2 = sock.connect_ex(('127.0.0.1',8119))
 sock.close()
```

In this case output of result2 is non zero integer....Is there any function in socket apart from close which I can use to get zero output in both cases....

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using TCP sockets you will need 1 socket per connection.
This means that you would have to make a new socket for each new connection, which is the case in your first example.

The `connect` and `close` functions will only work on the connection it is used with.
So multiple `connect` and `close` calls must be used for multiple connections.

E.g:

```
import socket
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock2 = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
result1 = sock.connect_ex(('127.0.0.1',9001))
result2 = sock2.connect_ex(('127.0.0.1',8119))
sock.close()
sock2.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot connect one socket twice.  Nor is it clear why you would want to.  Make two sockets, as you do in your first example.